# GPU scheduling in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, gpu

Please, does someone know how GPUs are scheduled in Linux? Is the Linux scheduler responsible for both CPU and GPU scheduler, or is it done in the hardware or by a driver?

For example, with DPU (Data Processing Unit), the scheduling algorithm is coded in the hardware and not handled by the software.

So, I would like to know if it is the same thing for GPU with Linux.

Comment: AFAIK the Linux scheduler is not employed in this at all, it's all down to the GPU driver. The scheduler allocates CPU time slices to running applications. It has not idea and doesn't care about anything else.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. Can you explain what exactly you mean with GPU scheduling?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thanks this answers my question

Answer (score 1):

The answer is provided by @ArtemS.Tashkinov:

> AFAIK the Linux scheduler is not employed in this at all, it's all
> down to the GPU driver. The scheduler allocates CPU time slices to
> running applications. It has not idea and doesn't care about anything
> else.